# Steady state heat equation with position-variable conductivity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Assuming a heat equation problem in $1$-D and applying finite difference method with points $x_0,..,x_n$ and some boundary condition on $x_0$ and $x_n$, the steady state solution equation can be described via the linear system of equations
\begin{equation*}
x_{i-1} - 2x_i + x_{i+1} = 0 \qquad i \in \{ 1,..., n-1\}
\end{equation*}
which corresponds to the Laplacian, but another easy interpretation would be something like to following:

We have $n$ discrete cells, each with their own total kinetic energy, and we assume that the boundary between each of them is of the same area. We can assume these boundaries act as barriers by default, but periodically we remove them, and let heat diffusion between neighboring cells happen for a while. When we do this, the kinetic energy is gained/lost by a cell, and the amount is proportional to the area of contact (cell boundary area) and the difference in temperature. We let this happen for a small amount of time, then we put the barriers back in, and let the heat become uniform in each cell, meaning the change in temperature in the cell is the amount of kinetic energy gained, divided by the total mass quantity of the cell.

Interestingly, there's no real demands on the conductivity (or the total mass of the cell, equivalently) with respect to position. This would imply that regardless of the material, the steady state solution to which the problem converges to is the same.

Is this correct?

I might be using the terms mass and conductivity wrong in this context, please correct the post if I am.

Comment: Please choose a title that actually fits your question. The title sounds like you are interested in a problem with non-constant conductivity, the rest of your post does not seem to support this.

Comment: @kricheli I don't see where I'm making any requirements on the conductivity being constant with respect to the position. The equation $x_{i-1} - 2x_i + x_{i+1} = 0$ only gets scaled by a scalar for different conductivity, so it stays the same.

Comment: @kricheli For a justification, I've written an explanation of why the equation makes sense, please tell me where it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one-dimensional steady-state heat equation is
$$
\partial_x \left(k \partial_x T\right) = 0
$$
with temperature $T$ and conductivity $k$. Only when $k$ is constant do you achieve the form you cite above in a discrete version. In that case $k$ would indeed be irrelevant for the steady-state solution and would only determine how fast the steady-state solution is approached, i.e. it defines the time scale of the relaxation towards equilibrium.

If $k$ depends on the position, you need to discretize the above equation including the conductivity.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I missed discretizing $k$, because I implicitly let it be constant on each little cell/neighborhood of a every $x_i$, and thought that made sense, but now I see that it doesn't, and I need to work with it as a non-constant variable in the discretization too.